# inserting node at ith position in linked list recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

would help me to solve this problem
i am trying to insert the node at ith location in linked list using recursion

here is the code please help me to imporve the code
i ma specifically facing problem at the end when i have to return the head i am not getting how to return

```
Node* insertNodeRecursively(Node*head, int n, int data)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        return head;
    }
    else if(n==0)
    {
        Node* newNode= new Node(data);
        newNode->next =  head->next;
        head->next = newNode;
        return head;
    }
  
    Node * x =  insertNodeRecursively(head->next,n-1,data);

    
   
    
}
```

Comment: There are multiple fundamental problems here. The shown code [needs to be reviewed by your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: You forgot to return a value when `n!=0`

Comment: thanks @SamVarshavchik 
rubber duck always help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess you want the function `insertNodeRecursively` to return the new head, right? Anything else would not work without considering the special case of inserting at position 0 in the caller function.

You could do the following:

```cpp
if (n == 0) {
    Node *newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode->next = head;
    return newNode;
}

if (head == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
}

Node *node = insertNodeRecursively(head->next, n - 1, data);
head->next = node;
return head;
```

The idea is that when this is not the position to insert to, we need to assume the next recursive call might give us a new head (from that position on), so we need that `head->next = node;` assignment. To call the node passed as first argument `head` might confuse as it is not always the head of the list (Only at the start of the recursion)! It is rather the node in front of which you want to insert in case n is 0. The problem with what you wrote in the `n == 0` case is that you always return the old head, even though you should return `newNode`. The `head` node should be what follows after `newNode`.